# elasticsearch - how to query relations

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the currenct structure:

```
localhost:9200/objects/content
{
    id:1,
    author:{
        name:"john"
    },
    body:"abc"
}

localhost:9200/objects/reaction
{
    content_id:1
    message:'I like it'
}
```

How can I query to get all reactions of contents writed by "john"?
This means a query on reactions, checking the content specified by id, if author is "someone".

Comment: I am not sure but i think that in your case you have no relation between your reaction and your contents (parent/child relation, or nested relation). I don't think that elasticsearch can execute query to automatically join your two types.

Answer (score 1):

This [Elasticsearch blog post](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch/) describes how to manage relationships inside Elasticsearch.

You will need to [set a parent mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-parent-field.html) between your reactions and your content.

```
{
    "reaction" : {
        "_parent" : {
            "type" : "content"
        }
    }
}
```

You will then index your reaction as a child of content id 1:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test/homes?parent=1 -d'
{
    message:'I like it'
}
```

You can then use a [Has Parent Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-child-query.html) to retrieve all reactions to authors named john:

```
{
    "has_parent" : {
        "parent_type" : "content",
        "query" : {
            "term" : {
                "author.name" : "john"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to add some redundancy to your model:

```
localhost:9200/objects/reaction
{
    content_id:1
    message:'I like it'
    author_name:'john'
}
```

This will increase the index, of course. On the other hand the query to get all `reactions of contents writed by "john"` will be simple and fast.